# Why change BIOS time to 01/01/1988, ubuntu installer can't find kernel?

Tags: system-installation, pxe

I am using PXE server to install Ubuntu 18.

There are two identical hardware systems.

System A with the correct date/time, ex: 6/11/2019

This system can install Ubuntu 18 via the same PXE server correctly.

System B with the incorrect date/time, ex: 1/1/1988

This system **can not** install Ubuntu 18 via the same PXE server correctly.

The error message is:

```
               [!!] Install the system

The installer cannot find a suitable kernel package to install.

<Go Back>                                           <Continue>
```

/////////// Update //////////

This issue can reproduce on System A as long as date/time change to 1/1/1988

Issue can be reproduced as long as BIOS date/time changed.

Comment: Old date is typical of a system that needs the coin battery on the motherboard replaced as it cannot hold UEFI/BIOS settings. That also then means any required UEFI/BIOS settings revert to defaults which may prevent booting. What brand/model system?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you trying to report a bug?

Comment: I don't understand why change BIOS time/date caused this problem.